# searches for all occurrences of a name that begins with a specific letter

Tags: c++, arrays, function

Write a function, searchName, that searches for all occurrences of a name that begins with a specific letter.  Store the subscripts in an array called searchResults that stores up to 20 elements then display the list on the screen.

**Here is the list of names:**

John P.
Mary Q.
Sam T.
Tom L.
Lisa O.
Teresa A.
Peter B.
Harris W.
Marcia D.
John G.
Lawrence F.
Amin C.
Jeffrey N.
Maria Z.
Cuong N.
Fila H.
Clark R.
Pedro J.
Jamie O.
Kevin Y.

**my code:**

```
void searchName(string n[], int lsize){
    int searchcount = 0;
    if(searchString[0] == n[i][0]){
        searchResults[searchcount] = 1;
}
```

Comment: Where is `names` defined?

Comment: Is `get` a function?  Is it a macro?  It's not a standalone identifier in C++.

Comment: Where is `i` defined?

Comment: You should post an [mcve], especially the "compilable" part.

Comment: We can see what you want to do, with a _part_ of your attempt.. What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//an index used to properly store new letters in an array
int nextPosition;
//the maximum length the array can be
const int LIST_LENGTH = 20;
//an array to store unique letters
char searchResults[LIST_LENGTH];
//an array to store each letters count
int searchCount[LIST_LENGTH];

// Note: because ^these variables are defined
// outside any function they can be used anywhere in the file

void searchName(string name) {

    //a 'flag' is used to tell if an entry for a letter has been recorded
    bool noEntryFound = true;

    //search unique letters for a match
    for (int j = 0; j < nextPosition; j++){
        //if the letter has been added already, increment it
        if ( searchResults[j] == name[0] ){

            searchCount[j] += 1;
            //found an entry, so this flag is alternated,
            // stopping more than 1 entry for the letter being added to array
            noEntryFound = false;
            //first letter is already in the array so breaking
            // the loop saves searching the rest of the array
            break;
        }

    }
    //if the array has been searched
    //and the letter wasn't found, add it, increment it
    if (noEntryFound == true){
        //store new letter, increment its count
        searchResults[nextPosition] = name[0];
        searchCount[nextPosition] += 1;
        //increment the position that new items get added to the array at
        nextPosition++;
    }

}

int main(){

    //the array of names of length 20 (LENGTH) 
    string names[LIST_LENGTH] = {
                        "John P.", "Mary Q.", "Sam T.",
                        "Tom L.","Lisa O.", "Teresa A.",
                        "Peter B.", "Harris W.", "Marcia D.",
                        "John G.", "Lawrence F.", "Amin C.","Jeffrey N.", 
                        "Maria Z.", "Cuong N.","Fila H.", "Clark R.",
                        "Pedro J.","Jamie O.", "Kevin Y."
                         };
    //iterate over all names as input for searchName
    for (int i=0; i < LIST_LENGTH; i++){
        searchName(names[i]);
    }
    //finally, print each letter and its equivalent count
    for (int k=0; k<nextPosition; k++){
        cout << searchResults[k] << " : " << searchCount[k] << endl;
    }
    return 1;
}
```